# Testing a neural network- after training

Tags: testing, delta, perceptron

I have wrote a code for training a single neuron network with the delta rule. another one for a perceptron that classifies 2 classes.
I trained them on 2000 samples and they work fine.

Now, I am looking to test them (with another 2000 samples) by using the last weights I gained at the end of the training process, and use them in the test code as follows:

```
function accuracy = test( data,weight1,weight2 )

xZero=1;
wZero=0.1;
counter=0;

for(n=1:2000)
    x1=data(n,1);
    x2=data(n,2);
    desired=data(n,3);

    y=(xZero*wZero)+(x1*weight1)+(x2*weight2);
    if(y==desired)
        counter=counter+1;
    end

end
```

but I am getting counter=0 which means no y values is equal to the desired value.
is that how we test the network or I missed something? I am trying to find an algorithm online or from books on how to test but I can't. do we have to have the same exact output as the desired output or should we use something like a threshold?

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of neural networks, but in this case it seems that you should have two outputs y1 and y2 in your network. After training the neural net you can get values of y1 and y2 for each test sample, then compute maximum of y1 and y2. The maximum determines the class of the sample.